# Powershell Get AD user group query

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script that will allow me to enter a user name and will then present me with all the groups that the user is a member of in AD. I have the following code which works when i run it in Powershell ISE but when i just run the script in Powershell it allows me to enter the username but closes as it has queried AD. It does not print the results out on the screen.

```
$username = Read-Host 'Please enter Username!'
get-aduser $username -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are pasting the code into an already open PowerShell terminal then yes, that is definitely weird.

If you are right clicking and "**Running with PowerShell**" then this is the expected behaviour because the script has finished. You'll need to tell the script to stay open after it has retrieved the information. The easiest way to do this is by telling the script to wait for your input using `Read-Host`

```
$username = Read-Host 'Please enter Username!'
get-aduser $username -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof
Read-Host 'Done!'
```

**UPDATE**

Using an if statement wouldn't be feasible since it only catches terminating errors and Get-ADUser doesn't return `terminating errors` you would need to use a `try/catch` block. I over engineered this solution use to show you how it could be done using different PowerShell features :)

```
#Function to search for the user
function searchUser{
    Param([string]$userName)
    try{
        Get-ADUser -Identity $userName -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf 
    }catch{
        return $false
    }
}

#Ask the user for input until a valid username is entered
do {
    $userInput = Read-Host "Enter a username: "
}until ($Output = searchUser -userName $userInput)

#Output the value from the searchUser function
Write-Host $Output
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to have worked. Would you know anything about adding an If-Else statement so if the username is valid it runs the code else it rails and asks you to re-enter the username?

Comment: its doing the same as last time? Where if you run it in ISE it works but if you right click on run with powershell it runs but doesn't print on screen?

Comment: @Will Please refer to the first example in my answer. It is outputting but closing straight after because the script is finished. Adding Read-Host to the end would be the easiest way to solve this

Comment: Perfect it seems to have worked. When it prints out the groups it does it all in the same rows. is there a way to separate them per group? so they are on separate rows?

Comment: @Will This is starting to get way out of the scope of your original question. Have you tried anything yourself?